How to filter out rows with empty lists in Pandas df?
I want to filter out rows containing empty lists in columns no_te_ins and te_ins.
Here is part of the input df te_filter:
             chr       family              no_te_ins                 te_ins
16   NC_064017.1        uc|28         [P1-88, P1-92]                     []
493  NC_064017.1   Stowaway|1                     []                     []
494  NC_064017.1        uc|31                     []  [P1-12, P1-22, P1-25]
495  NC_064017.1         uc|9         [P1-25, P1-93]  [P1-12, P1-26, P1-28]

Here is the part of the code:
te_filter['te_ins'] = te_filter['te_ins'].astype(str)
te_filter['no_te_ins'] = te_filter['no_te_ins'].astype(str)

te_filter_final = te_filter[te_filter['no_te_ins'] != '[]']
print(te_filter_final.to_string)

te_filter_final_2 = te_filter[te_filter['te_ins'] != '[]']
print(te_filter_final_2.to_string)

It works good for no_te_ins column an the output for te_filter_final is:
             chr     family               no_te_ins                       te_ins
16   NC_064017.1      uc|28      ['P1-88', 'P1-92']                         ['']
495  NC_064017.1       uc|9      ['P1-25', 'P1-93']  ['P1-12', 'P1-26', 'P1-28']

but for te_ins it doesn't remove the desired rows (there is no effect) and the output for te_filter_final_2 is the same as the input (only the values in te_ins column is changed from [] to [''] (?):
             chr       family             no_te_ins                       te_ins
16   NC_064017.1        uc|28    ['P1-88', 'P1-92']                         ['']
493  NC_064017.1   Stowaway|1                    []                         ['']
494  NC_064017.1        uc|31                    []  ['P1-12', 'P1-22', 'P1-25']
495  NC_064017.1         uc|9    ['P1-25', 'P1-93']  ['P1-12', 'P1-26', 'P1-28']

Any idea what's going on? Is there something wrong with the data type and how to fix it?

you can try using this to check for an empty list instead: df[df["col"].str.len() != 0]

It's not working, still the same output..

If the suggestion by @iBeMeltin is not working, then potentially you don't have proper lists in those columns. To avoid all this ambiguity, please add your data sample via df.to_dict(). And then please reduce it to what is actually necessary to illustrate the problem, creating a [mre]. There are lots of columns here, which clearly are not relevant to the actual issue.

what happens if you remove the conversion astype(str) and then use the code i suggested?

@ouroboros1, I reduced the data and now it is more readable I hope. After removing the conversion there was still no effect but I checked the data types inside lists and the problem was with an empty string inside the list in the column te_ins. I removed it with te_filter['te_ins'].apply(lambda x: list(filter(None, x))) and now everything is working well. Thanks for the tips!

@emor: so you managed to answer your own question then, no? If so, well done and good luck with the project :) ! For future ref, the advice to use df.to_dict() still stands. See, even now, the data in your Q is ambiguous. E.g., you're now showing values like [''], but I would get such a print from both pd.Series(["['']"]) (containing a string) and pd.Series([['']]) (containing a list). So, to avoid such ambiguity, do not post such prints, but the constructors themselves.

Try this:
te_filter[te_filter['te_ins'].map(len) > 0]

